# Need to change text of <a> with text from a variable list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down that only shows up when an user access the website from a specific country. In this drop down there are two list elements with anchor tags in each. I need to change the anchor tags text with some data from my variable list.

Here is my list:

```
<div class="geo-location-button" style="text-decoration: none"><p>Take me to Global</p>
     <ul class="geo-list">
        <li class="one"><a id="first" href="#\"> E-Commerce Portal </a></li>
        <li class="two"><a id="second" href="#\"> Website </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
if (list[jo].url === undefined) {
   $('.geo-list .one a').text(list[jo].text2);
}
```

Here is an example of my variable list called 'jo'

```
'United States': {
      text: "Take me to United States",
      text2: "E-Commerce Portal",
      text3: "Website",
      url: '',
      url2: 'https://www.bestbuy.com',
      url3: 'http://www.google.com'
      },  


'United Kingdom': {
      text: "Take me to  UK",
      url: 'http://www.google.co.uk'
      },
```

As you can see from my script, I want to change the text of the anchor within the list only when a country from my variable list does not have a value for 'url', therfore having more than one options in both text values (text2,text3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a typo there, you have `one` instead of `.one`.

```
$('.geo-list .one a').text(list[jo].text2);
```

Another thing if your `url` is `''` then `url === undefined` will return `false`. What you want is `url === undefined || url == ''`

Comment: I do feel like an idiot for not double checking first, however it still seems to not work.  My code is like this: if (list[jo].url === undefined) {
                $('.geo-list .one a').text(list[jo].text2);
                $('.geo-list .two a').text(list[jo].text3);
              }

Comment: Well, quite simple, if your url is `''` then `url === undefined` will return `false`. What you want is `url === undefined || url == ''`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It worked perfectly! Could you add this to your answer so I can mark it correct

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the dot in front of the `.one` class selector.

```
if (list[jo].url === undefined) {
  $('.geo-list .one a').text(list[jo].text2);
  $('.geo-list .two a').text(list[jo].text3);
  ... etc
}
```

Comment: yes I have fixed it and my code looks exactly like yours. Somehow it is still not changing the text.

Answer (score 1):

Please use . before a class while refering in jquery

```
if (list[jo].url === undefined) {
   $('.geo-list .one a').text(list[jo].text2);
}
```